# Back reference Regular Expression not working in sed

Tags: regex, linux, sed

Team,

I have one file with the below data.

```
[root@ip-1-32-3-67 ~]# cat db

555

555

555

666

666

777
```

I need to add the string "First" in front of all string

## Expect Output:

```
First: 555

First: 555

First: 555

First: 666

First: 666

First: 777
```

My sed command look like.

```
[root@ip-1-32-8-1 ~]# sed -e 's/\([0-9]+\)/First: \1/g' db

555

555

555

666

666

777
```

But the output not adding First. Please help me out where i am doing the mistake.

Comment: Use `sed -r ...`, not `-e`, `sed -r 's/[0-9]+/First &/'`. To perform inline replacement: `sed -i -r 's/[0-9]+/First &/' db`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew  Please give me the complete command

Comment: Use `sed -r 's/[0-9]+/First &/'`. To perform inline replacement: `sed -i -r 's/[0-9]+/First &/' db`.  Also, `sed 's/[0-9][0-9]*/First &/'` will work, too.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Thanks its working. One more help how to more than one back reference Example: First:  \1 and Second:  \2 and so on how to do it

Comment: This is the file content   (555)555-1212
(555)555-1213
(555)555-1214
(666)555-1215
(666)555-1216
(777)555-1217  Expected output: First: (555)  Second: 555-  Third: 1214 and so on

Comment: Please update the question with the new string. Is the format of the string always the same? What is the expected output? Actually, that looks like a dfferent problem though.

Answer (score 0):

You passed a BRE POSIX pattern to the `sed` command, and thus `(`, `)` and `+` were treated as literal chars.

You may either replace `-e` with `-r` to make the pattern get parsed as a POSIX ERE, or use

```
sed 's/[0-9][0-9]*/First &/'
```

where `[0-9][0-9]*` matches 1 or more digits and `&` in the replacement part inserts the whole match.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `g` and `+` doesn't have a special meaning in this context (BRE syntax). If your file is as said, you could use:

```
sed 's/^./First: &/' file
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Command working fine. But for this file (555)555-1212
(555)555-1213  Expect output: First: (555)  Second: 555-  Third: 1213 .How to achieve the above output

Comment: Use `sed 's/^\(([^)]*)\)\([0-9]*-\)\([0-9]*\)/First: \1\nSecond: \2\nThird: \3\n/' file`